# Regex For Checking Duplicates

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a HTML/JS bingo game. It needs to have functionality that lets users specify their own bingo board by entering a string that needs to be validated using a regex. The specifications are as follows:

The string format will be

- B(15,9,8,7,14)I(25,21,20,22,29)N(38,41,f,34,31)G(60,57,48,56,49)O(69,70,72,64,71)
  where B(15,9,8,7,14) means that the B column on the board contains
  15, 9, 8, 7, and 14. I(25,21,20,22,29) means the I column contains
  25, 21, 20, 22 and 29. And so forth. 'f' is used in the string to
  represent the free space.

So far I have:

```js
var string = /(B|b)(((1[0-5]|[1-9]),?){5})(I|i)(((1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30),?){5})(N|n)(((3[1-9]|4[0-5]),){2}(F|f),((3[1-9]|4[0-5]),?){2})(G|g)(((4[6-9]|5[0-9]|60),?){5})(O|o)(((6[1-9]|7[0-5]),?){5})/g;
```

Which validates the above example but doesn't check for duplicates. I.e., B(15,15,8,7,14)... should fail. I think negative lookahead is the right tool to use but i'm unsure how to use it in this context

Comment: `([BINGO])\((\d+(?:,\d+){4}|\d+,\d+,f,\d+,\d+)\)` then split capture group 2 on `,` to ensure numbers are within appropriate ranges (as I assume you'll want to do) + ensuring only `N` (identified by capture group 1)contains `f`

Comment: Did you know that you don't need the letters?
B can only be: 1-15, I:16-30, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract numbers from string into an Array, and check for duplicates:

```js
var bingoStrings = [
  "B(15,9,8,7,14)I(25,21,20,22,29)N(38,41,f,34,31)G(60,57,48,56,49)O(69,70,72,64,71)",
  "B(15,15,8,7,14)I(25,21,20,22,29)N(38,41,f,34,31)G(60,57,48,56,49)O(69,70,72,64,71)"
];

bingoStrings.forEach(bingoString => {
  var bingoArray = bingoString.match(/\d+/g);
  var hasDuplicates = bingoArray.some(number =>
    bingoArray.indexOf(number) !== bingoArray.lastIndexOf(number)
  );
  console.log(bingoString);
  console.log("has " + (hasDuplicates?"":"no ") + "duplicates\n");
});
```

As a function:

```js
var bingoStrings = [
  "B(15,9,8,7,14)I(25,21,20,22,29)N(38,41,f,34,31)G(60,57,48,56,49)O(69,70,72,64,71)",
  "B(15,15,8,7,14)I(25,21,20,22,29)N(38,41,f,34,31)G(60,57,48,56,49)O(69,70,72,64,71)"
];

hasDuplicates = (bingoString) => 
  bingoString
  .match(/\d+/g)
  .some((number, index, bingoArray) =>
    bingoArray.indexOf(number) !== bingoArray.lastIndexOf(number)
  )
;
  
bingoStrings.forEach(bingoString => {
  console.log(bingoString);
  console.log("has " + (hasDuplicates(bingoString)?"":"no ") + "duplicates\n");
});
```